# Performance of JBLAS

Tags: java

I wanna perform heavy matrix multiplication

Since my app need high performance, I decided to use JBLAS.

However, I discovered JBLAS is slower than simple for loop in the test.

```
    double[][] M = new double[3000][3100];
    double[] a = new double [3100];
    double[] b = new double[3000];
    for(double[] row: M){
        Arrays.fill(row, 3.343);
    }
    Arrays.fill(a, 1.324);
    DoubleMatrix M1 = new DoubleMatrix(M);
    DoubleMatrix a1 = new DoubleMatrix(a);
    DoubleMatrix b1= new DoubleMatrix(b);

    //1. Simple for loop : 366 ms
    for(int i=0; i<3000; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<3100; j++){
            b[i] = b[i] + a[j]*M[i][j];
        }
    }
    // 2. JBLAS : 1190 ms
    b1 = M1.mmul(a1);
```

Although they are same calculation, JBLAS is 3 times slower than simple for loop.

Is it due to my mistake? or other reasons?

Thank you!

Comment: Look into a profiler to determine the actual source of slowness.  It'd be faster than us trying to do something very similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution myself, and share it!

The reason is that native code involves copying the data, so an operation like matrix vector multiplication cannot benefit from native code.

So, if mmul function recognize matrix*vector multiplication, it uses Java code.

You can get more information here 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jblas-users/HY2acEE3Y10

Comment: Posting the link as an answer is not allowed. You must provide and explain the core of the answer in the post here. You can, however, provide the link for extra information (for those who are interested)